# NODE.JS slow on connections test

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to test servers availability with **NODE.JS** something like server monitoring.
I created test CSV file with **5000 domains** in it and used the code bellow:

```
var net = require('net');

function Daemon(address,name, port) {
  this.address = address;
  this.name = name;
  this.port = port;
}

var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('domains.csv').toString().split("\n");
for(i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    daemons.push(new Daemon(array[i],'http', 80));
}

// loop through each daemon in the array
daemons.forEach(function(d) {

  // create the TCP stream to the server
  var stream = net.createConnection(d.port, d.address);
    console.log('[' + d.address + ']\t connected');

  // listen for connection
  stream.on('connect', function(){

    // connection success
    //console.log('[' + d.name + ']\t connected');

    stream.end(); // close the stream
  });

  // listen for any errors
  stream.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('[' + d.name + ']\t error: ' + error);

    stream.destroy(); // close the stream

  });
});
```

There are many timeouts for particular domains:

```
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
[http]   error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

But this code is slow. It takes almost 30 minutes to finish it. How can I speed up the this code (asynchronous connections) ?

I need the script to be able to test **100.000 domains in every 5 minutes**

Comment: I think your connections are async, it just has to timeout before throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

net.createConnection is non blocking so you already have asynchronous connections.

I tried your code with 500 ips and it took less than 10 secs for accepted or refused connections, only the TIMEOUT ones took a bit longer (30-40 secs)

If you want to do more async, use async module ^^
Your loop will look like :

```
async.forEach(
    daemons, 
    function(daemon) {
       //Your connect stuff
    },
    function(err){}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that at one point, opening 5000 outbound TCP connections is not good for your system. You should limit concurrent connection attempts to a reasonable number.

I suggest you use [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) with a concurrency of 100 or 200.